# $k$-jets , submanifolds

Tags: manifolds, jet-bundles

I am trying to solve this problem:

Let $J^k (n,p)$ be the set of maps $\sigma:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^p$, where $\sigma_i$ (the coordinate functions) is a polynomial of degree $\leq k$ with null constant term. We call such space as $k$-th jet bundle.

a) Let $\Sigma^i\subset J^1(n,1)$ be the set of $\sigma$ such that $\dim (\ker(\sigma))=i$. Show that $\Sigma^i$ is the empty set or is a submanifold. In the last case, calculate its dimension.

b) Given $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$, for each $p\in\mathbb{R}^n$ define the function
$$j^1 f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow J^1(n,1),$$
where $$j^1 f(p)(x_1,\dots, x_n)=\frac{\partial f(p)}{\partial x_1}x_1+\dots+\frac{\partial f(p)}{\partial x_n}x_n.$$

Show that $f$ is a Morse function if, and only if, $j^1 f \pitchfork\Sigma^n$ for each singular point $p$ of $f$.

So far what I did notice was that $J^1(n,1)$ can be identified with $\mathbb{R}^n$ and he admits only $\Sigma^{n}$ and $\Sigma^{n-1}$ not empty.

Comment: I think your observation is the key step. $J^{1}(n,1)$ should just be the dual of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $\Sigma^{n-1}$ is all nonzero functionals and $\Sigma^{n}$ contains just the $0$ functional. Are these submanifolds? For the second part, perhaps you could use this characterization of $\Sigma^{n}$ along with the definition of a Morse function.

Comment: Yup! Indeed, the exercise is immediate from the identification with $\mathbb{R}^n$! Thank you.